# Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically error

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am using server actions in my server component. But I get this error when I deploy website to vercel. How can I fix this type of problem ? I am using next.js 14

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { Heart, MapPin, MoreHorizontal } from "lucide-react";
import { getVacanciesData } from "@/lib/actions/vacancies";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Badge } from "../ui/badge";
import NotFound from "../shared/NotFound";

const FeaturedVacancies = async () => {
  const vacanciesData = await getVacanciesData({
    isPremium: true,
    take: 3,
  });
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 md:gap-7">
    </div>
  );
};

export default FeaturedVacancies;
```

That's my featured vacancies component ( not page ).

```
import FeatureCard from "@/components/cards/FeatureCard";
import FeaturedVacancies from "@/components/home/FeaturedVacancies";
import Hero from "@/components/home/Hero";
import InformationalCard from "@/components/home/InformationalCard";
import PopularTags from "@/components/home/PopularTags";
import { JobCategories } from "@/components/shared/JobCategories";
import OurCustomers from "@/components/shared/OurCustomers";

export default async function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="">
      <Hero />

      <div className="mt-20 mb-24">
        <OurCustomers />
      </div>

      <div className="mt-20 mb-24">
        <FeaturedVacancies />
      </div>

      <div className="my-28">
        <JobCategories />
      </div>

      <div className="my-28 grid grid-cols-12 gap-10">
        <div className="col-span-6">
          <InformationalCard />
        </div>

        <div className="col-span-6">
          <PopularTags />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="my-28">
        <FeatureCard />
      </div>

      <div className="my-28">
        <FeatureCard featureID={1} side="left" />
      </div>

      <div className="mt-28">
        <FeatureCard featureID={2} />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

That's my home page. Where I am using FeaturedVacancies

```
"use server";
import { startOfDay, startOfMonth, startOfWeek } from "date-fns";
import db from "../db";

export const getVacanciesData = async (filter = {}) => {
  try {
    let status = "ACTIVE";

    const {
      postedDate,
      jobType,
      city,
      skip = 0,
      take = 10,
      search = "",
      isPremium,
    } = filter;

    let timeAgo = new Date();

    if (postedDate === "day") {
      timeAgo.setDate(timeAgo.getDate() - 1);
      timeAgo.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (postedDate === "week") {
      timeAgo.setDate(timeAgo.getDate() - 7);
      timeAgo.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (postedDate === "month") {
      timeAgo.setDate(timeAgo.getDate() - 30);
      timeAgo.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
      timeAgo = undefined;
    }

    const vacancies = await db.vacancyUserCompanyAssociation.findMany({
      where: {
        OR: [
          {
            vacancy: {
              name: { contains: search || undefined, mode: "insensitive" },
            },
          },
          {
            company: {
              name: { contains: search || undefined, mode: "insensitive" },
            },
          },
        ],
        vacancy: {
          status: status || undefined,
          regime: jobType || undefined,
          city: city || undefined,
          isPremium: isPremium || undefined,
          activatedAt: {
            gte: timeAgo || undefined,
          },
        },
      },

      include: {
        company: {
          select: {
            id: true,
            name: true,
            logo: true,
          },
        },
        vacancy: {
          select: {
            id: true,
            name: true,
            category: true,
            city: true,
            regime: true,
            salary: true,
            currency: true,
            minimum: true,
            maximum: true,
            responsibilities: true,
            requirements: true,
            createdAt: true,
            status: true,
            activatedAt: true,
            isPremium: true,
            slug: true,
          },
        },
      },
      orderBy: [
        {
          vacancy: {
            isPremium: "desc",
          },
        },
        {
          vacancy: {
            activatedAt: "desc",
          },
        },
      ],
      skip: skip,
      take: take,
    });


    const vacanciesData = vacancies.map((data) => ({
      company: data.company,
      ...data.vacancy,
    }));

    return { data: vacanciesData };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

That's my vacancies server action. I can use this server action in my /vacancies page without any problem. But I can not use this server action in my FeaturedVacancies component. I got this error

In error image it says /api/admin/company/getAll. But when I delete FeaturedVacancies from home page I got 0 error on my deployment process. That's my getAll route

```
import db from "@/lib/db";
import { decode } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req, res) {
  try {
    const cookies = req.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token")?.value;
    const status = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("status");

    let userId;
    let userRole;

    if (cookies) {
      const decoded = await decode({
        token: cookies,
        secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
      });

      userId = decoded.sub;
      userRole = decoded.roleName;
    }

    if (!userId) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "User required" }, { status: 400 });
    }

    if (userRole !== "ADMIN") {
      return NextResponse({ message: "Access denied" }, { status: 401 });
    }


    // Fetch companies associated with the specified userId
    const companies = await db.company.findMany({
      where: {
        status: status,
      },
    });

    // Respond with the fetched companies
    return NextResponse.json(companies, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching companies:", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Internal Server Error" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCHFx.png)

Comment: From the attached error image, the error looks to be in the `/app/api/admin/company/getAll/route.js`, can you include the code inside this route in your description.

Comment: I added it. but when I delete featuredvacancies component, I didn't get any error in my deployment process. How this two different server action and route related to each other ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `FeaturedVacancies` page is built statically, you can opt out of this and force dynamic rendering by adding the following

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"
```

Your `FeaturedVacanices` page would look like

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { Heart, MapPin, MoreHorizontal } from "lucide-react";
import { getVacanciesData } from "@/lib/actions/vacancies";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Badge } from "../ui/badge";
import NotFound from "../shared/NotFound";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

const FeaturedVacancies = async () => {
  const vacanciesData = await getVacanciesData({
    isPremium: true,
    take: 3,
  });
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 md:gap-7">
    </div>
  );
};

export default FeaturedVacancies;
```

Comment: I added 

`export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";` but nothing changed. Again I am getting same error. I have updated my main content and added home page also

Comment: @ReactLover Are you certain this is the page causing the error? Are you accessing cookies anywhere in your project?

Comment: I am accessing cookies yes. But I use this server action in more than 1 component and pages. And everywhere it's working smoothly. Just in this component it gives error, I can not figure out what is problem why I get this type of problem. I added force-dynamic to home page. Now getting `Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information).` error from vercel

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue might be how the `FeaturedVacancies` component is rendered.
The `FeaturedVacancies` is an async component and performs an async operation, and you are rendering this component in the `Home` component without awaiting the promise. This can cause the lose of original async context which causes the dynamic server error, you can read more about it in [Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error#scenarios-that-can-cause-this-to-happen)

I would suggest moving the call to `getVacanciesData` to the `Home` component and passing the `vacanciesData` as a prop to `FeaturedVacancies` component (this component doesn't have to be async now)

Here's what that might look like

`Home` component

```
export default async function Home() {
 const vacanciesData = await getVacanciesData({
isPremium: true,
take: 3,
 });

  return (
    <main className="">
      <Hero />

      <div className="mt-20 mb-24">
        <OurCustomers />
      </div>

      <div className="mt-20 mb-24">
        <FeaturedVacancies vacanciesData={vacanciesData} />
      </div>

      <div className="my-28">
        <JobCategories />
      </div>

      <div className="my-28 grid grid-cols-12 gap-10">
        <div className="col-span-6">
          <InformationalCard />
        </div>

        <div className="col-span-6">
          <PopularTags />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="my-28">
        <FeatureCard />
      </div>

      <div className="my-28">
        <FeatureCard featureID={1} side="left" />
      </div>

      <div className="mt-28">
        <FeatureCard featureID={2} />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

`FeaturedVacancies` component

```
const FeaturedVacancies = ({vacanciesData}) => {
  // verify the vacanices data is being passed correctly
  console.log(vacanciesData)
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 md:gap-7">
    </div>
  );
};

export default FeaturedVacancies;
```

If this works, you can then reorganize your components, the key is to not render a child component performing async operation directly.

Comment: I have tried it already. Giving me same error. Right now I am trying to remove all my cookies from routes and use getToken({}) function instead of it. After that will try deployment again

Comment: Did it but nothing changed. This next.js documentation and community is so poor. Can not get any information from internet, can not create bug report it asks codesandbox or github, totally ridiculous